# How to call a PHP function after a javascript setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a school project, and I cannot wrap my head around this issue. I am not experienced with JQuery/AJAX.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is executing a PHP-function after a set amount of time (after a notification disappears).

What I've tried thus far did not work as expected, though the JQuery does execute (I get the success message).

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        (document.querySelectorAll('.notification .delete') || []).forEach(($delete) => {
            $notification = $delete.parentNode;
                $notification.parentNode.removeChild($notification);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '../app/functions.php',
            type: "post",
            data: { "deleteNotification": "true" },
            success: function () {
                alert('Test');
            }
        });
    }, 5000)
```

The PHP-Code I'm then calling is this:

```php
    if (isset($_POST['deleteNotification'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['notifications']);
    }
```

For some reason, the PHP code does not execute, although it should. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Did you open your browser console to see what ajax request returns? Add a `var_dump($_POST);` to the top of your `functions.php` script

Comment: "For some reason, the PHP code does not execute, although it should" -- How do you know?

Comment: Please show us your full php code

Comment: The problem was me not including the php code where I started the session. Dumb mistake, but easily overlooked. Thanks for the answers.